# How to specify classpath when compile

Tags: java, classpath

The source java file uses system libraries and 3rd library;

The 3rd party jar files are under ./lib

The system lib/class used:

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
```

This command runs ok:

```
javac.exe -g .\jms\example\SimpleDemo.java
```

But if I specify classpath as the followings, no way of the following variations  works:

```
-cp .;%JAVA_HOME%
-cp .;%CLASSPATH%;%JAVA_HOME%;.\lib\*.jar
```

What's wrong here to specify classpath?

I wonder compile doesn't need to specify classpath, it's only needed when run the generated class file, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the point:

There must be wildcard * in the classpath, and not *.jar

```
javac.exe -classpath .\lib\* -g .\jms\example\SimpleDemo.java
```

.\lib*.* or .\lib*.jar or .\lib doesn't work;

The system libraries don't need to add into classpath;

According to the document http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html:

A class path entry that contains * will not match .class files

The wildcard * can only refer to jar files;

"*The class path tells JDK tools and applications where to find third-party and user-defined classes*"

This means, Java system libraries don't need classpath;

The following means directory only  in classpath is only for .class files;

*For .class files in an unnamed package, the class path ends with the directory that contains the .class files.*

*For .class files in a named package, the class path ends with the directory that contains the "root" package (the first package in the full package name).*

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "I wonder compile doesn't need to specify classpath...";

javac definitely needs to specify classpath if the libraries are not specified in env variable CLASSPATH, but system libraries don't need to be in the classpath as javac command can recognise by itself.